# Big Query Delete double using a non legacy sql request via the API

Tags: sql, node.js, google-bigquery

I have a table with double, I want to delete them via the API using a non legacy sql request to delete them directly without using a SELECT statement.

How to use the DELETE statement in order to achieve this ?

Comment: DML (e.g. `DELETE`) is only available in Standard SQL. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-manipulation-language

Comment: Yes you're right, I don't want to use legacy, I'm editing my post